# Overlay a normal distribution in Highcharts R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have vector that contains the stock market returns. I would like to add a normal distribution to the plot in highcharts. I have tried using dnorm() but cant seem to figure out how to plot it on the graph. I have made a work around by creating a vector using rnorm(). That said, I have to use 20k points in order for it to remove the bumps. This is time consuming.

Here is my current workaround

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

getSymbols("SPY")
returns = na.omit(coredata(ROC(Ad(SPY))))
r = rnorm(20000, mean = 0, sd = sd(returns))

hchart(
  density(returns), type = "area", 
  name = "SPY"
) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    density(r), type = "area",
    name = "Normal"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by saying removing the bumps? To make them exactly be matched? If it is the case, I think you should change the sigma of the normal distribution. It won't be a perfect match but  `r = rnorm(20000, mean = 0, sd = sd(returns)/2)`  makes them be closer.

Comment: @maydin because rnorm() creates actual number it will not be a perfect normal distribution. You can see this because the black line is not smooth - it has bumps. I would like to plot something like dnorm() where it creates a perfect normal distro

Comment: [This](https://easystats.github.io/blog/posts/bayestestr_distribution/) link may be helpful  then...

Comment: Aside: You may not want to fit a normal distribution to your stock returns, as it is typically not the best fit. You may want to consider a Johnson SU distribution instead (more info [here](https://medium.com/@courtney.clarke/i-published-my-first-r-package-75782b29ac41)). In this case, there is an R package ([JSUparameters](https://cran.r-project.org/package=JSUparameters)) that will find the parameters of the best fitting JSU distribution for your data, which you could then overlay on your plot.